# Infix to Postfix using C stuck execution after halfway. Can any one tell me why?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, stack, singly-linked-list

I've been trying implementing Infix to Postfix using Stack(using LL) in C Language. When I first executed the code with input like(e.g: a+b/c*d-e) it's showing the correct notation from infix to postfix. So I think Everything is working fine but after modifying the code to accept input consisting brackets when I'm trying to input expressions having brackets its gets stuck mid way of execution. I don't know why?
Please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Below is the Code

````
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stackPara
{
    char data;
    struct stackPara *next;
};

int isEmpty(struct stackPara *top)
{
    if (top == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int isFull(struct stackPara *top)
{
    struct stackPara *p = (struct stackPara *)malloc(sizeof(struct stackPara));
    if (p == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

struct stackPara *pushStack(struct stackPara *top, char n)
{
    struct stackPara *ptr = (struct stackPara *)malloc(sizeof(struct stackPara));
    ptr->data = n;
    if (!isFull(top))
    {
        ptr->next = top;
        top = ptr;
        //printf("Insert %c\n", top->data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Stack is FULL");
    }
    return top;
}
char popStack(struct stackPara **top)
{
    char x = '\0';
    struct stackPara *p = (*top);
    if (!isEmpty((*top)))
    {
        x = (*top)->data;
        (*top) = (*top)->next;
        free(p);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Stack is Empty");
    }
    return x;
}
void displayLL(struct stackPara *ptr)
{
    // struct stackPara *ptr=top;
    printf("Elements of Stack are:\n");
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Data:%d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
int isOperand(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' || ch >= '1' && ch <= '9');
}
int isOperator(char ch)
{
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
        return 1;
    if (ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        return 2;
    if (ch == '^')
        return 3;
    return 0;
}
void infixToPostfix(char *exp)
{
    struct stackPara *top = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isOperator(exp[i]))
        {
            if (isEmpty(top))
            {
                top = pushStack(top, exp[i]);
                // printf("%c",exp[i]);
                // displayLL(top);
            }
            else
            {
                if (isOperator(exp[i]) > isOperator(top->data))
                {
                    top = pushStack(top, exp[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    while (!isEmpty(top))
                    {
                        if (isOperator(exp[i]) <= isOperator(top->data))
                        {
                            printf("%c", popStack(&top));
                        }
                    }
                    top = pushStack(top, exp[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (isOperand(exp[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", exp[i]);
        }
        if (exp[i] == '(')
            top = pushStack(top, exp[i]);
        else if (exp[i] == ')')
        {
            while (top->data != '(')
            {
                printf("%c", popStack(&top));
            }
            if (top->data == '(')
            {
                popStack(&top);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID EXPRESSION");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (!isEmpty(top))
    {
        printf("%c", popStack(&top));
    }
}
int main()
{
    char *exp = "a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i\0";
    infixToPostfix(exp);
    return 0;
}```


> Output of Above Code:
> 
> **abcd^**
````

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. I see at least one `while` loop that might never end.

Comment: can u elaborate which while loop?

Comment: `while (!isEmpty(top)) { if (isOperator(exp[i]) <= isOperator(top->data)) { printf("%c", popStack(&top));  } }` could go on forever if the condition is never true. That might not be the case (there's a lot of code here)  but the point is if you use a debugger you can pinpoint where it is stuck.

Comment: the ìsFull`function does something very weird. It just wastes memory.
It will return 1 until you are out of memory.
That may not  be why your program stops, but it is totally wrong.
It should just be `return top != NULL`